# How to write SQLite database in Fragment Android

Tags: android

while I am creating a database on android SQLite database with fragment if I write inside the onViewCreated method couldn't write the database name and Listview findViewById get the error I don't know. what I tried so I wrote below.

cannot resolve the method openOrCreateDatabase

```
  SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("course", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);


  lst1 = findViewById(R.id.lst1);
```

cannot resolve the method findViewById

cannot resolve the constructor ArrayAdapter

```
 **arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, titles);**`


 lst1 = findViewById(R.id.lst1);
 ListView lst1;
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
        @Override
       public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("course", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            lst1 = findViewById(R.id.lst1);
            final Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from category", null);
            int id = c.getColumnIndex("id");
            int title = c.getColumnIndex("title");
            int description = c.getColumnIndex("description");

            titles.clear();
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, titles);
            lst1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            final ArrayList<cate> cat = new ArrayList<cate>();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    cate stu = new cate();
                    stu.id = c.getString(id);
                    stu.course = c.getString(title);
                    stu.description = c.getString(description);
                    cat.add(stu);
                    titles.add(c.getString(id) + " \t " + c.getString(title) );

                } while (c.moveToNext());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lst1.invalidateViews();
            }
            lst1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String aa = titles.get(position).toString();
                    cate stu = cat.get(position);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editcategory.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", stu.id);
                    i.putExtra("category", stu.course);
                    i.putExtra("description", stu.description);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly call `openOrCreateDatabase()` in a fragment because it is a method from `Context`. A fragment is not a context. To get the context / Activity, just call `getActivity()`

It will result in the following :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("course", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

For `findViewById()` you have to call that on the parent view

```
view.findViewById(R.id.lst1);
```

For the adapter constructor, `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item` is not a string but an id from R class, so no need for `'`

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, titles);
```

Comment: Sir  arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, titles); this is not woring how to write Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editcategory.class); Intend also not working

Comment: in the constructor, in the same way, `this` is not a context, so you nedd `getActivity()` again. See the updated answer

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editcategory.class);  how to write this

Comment: again, `getActivity()` ... -> `Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), editcategory.class);` But don't ask questions in comment, post a new question directly